# Passing variables to PHP method

Tags: php, function

I've a php function ,

```
func($c) {

global $a,$b;

//Do something

}
```

I call it like this,

```
$c = "Test";
func($c);
```

But in some cases I need to pass an extra parameter $b and it should not be overridden by the global variable value so i tried this,

```
func($c,$b = $b,$a = $a) {

//Do something

}
```

But in PHP setting variable as default is not permitted. So kindly help me here ...

Comment: I don't get your question? Please elaborate what you wish to do or achieve?

Comment: That code you posted is not even valid PHP code.... Besides that, global variables are usually bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to use a global var as the default value of a function argument?
You can use the following code assuming `null` is never passed as a valid argument.

```
function func($c, $b = null, $a = null) {
    if($b === null) $b = $GLOBALS['b'];
    if($a === null) $a = $GLOBALS['b'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

May that will help you.

```
<?php

    function doWork($options)
    {
        extract(
            merge_array(
                array(
                    'option_1' => default_value,
                    'option_2' => default_value,
                    'option_3' => default_value,
                    'option_x' => default_value
                ),
                $options
            )
        );

        echo $option_1; // Or do what ever you like with option_1
    }

    $opts = array(
        'option_1' => custom_value,
        'option_3' => another_custom_value
    );
```